# Is there a reason why `this` is nullified in Crockford's `curry` method?

Tags: javascript, partial-application

In Douglas Crockford's book "Javascript: The Good Parts" he provides code for a `curry` method which takes a function and arguments and returns that function with the arguments already added (apparently, this is not really [what "curry" means](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/currying/info), but is an example of ["partial application"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/partial-application/info)). Here's the code, which I have modified so that it works without some other custom code he made:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function(){
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
      args = slice.apply(arguments),
      that = this;
  return function() {
    // context set to null, which will cause `this` to refer to the window
    return that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
  };
};
```

So if you have an `add` function:

```
var add = function(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
};

add(2, 4);          // returns 6
```

You can make a new function that already has one argument:

```
var add1 = add.curry(1);

add1(2);           // returns 3
```

That works fine. But what I want to know is why does he set `this` to `null`? Wouldn't the expected behavior be that the curried method is the same as the original, including the same `this`?

My version of curry would look like this:

```
Function.prototype.myCurry = function(){
  var slice = [].slice,
      args = slice.apply(arguments),
      that = this;
  return function() {
    // context set to whatever `this` is when myCurry is called
    return that.apply(this, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
  };
};
```

**Example**

**[(Here is a jsfiddle of the example)](http://jsfiddle.net/38z2r/5/)**

```
var calculator = {
  history: [],
  multiply: function(num1, num2){
    this.history = this.history.concat([num1 + " * " + num2]);
    return num1 * num2;
  },
  back: function(){
    return this.history.pop();
  }
};

var myCalc = Object.create(calculator);
myCalc.multiply(2, 3);         // returns 6
myCalc.back();                 // returns "2 * 3"
```

If I try to do it Douglas Crockford's way:

```
myCalc.multiplyPi = myCalc.multiply.curry(Math.PI);
myCalc.multiplyPi(1);          // TypeError: Cannot call method 'concat' of undefined
```

If I do it my way:

```
myCalc.multiplyPi = myCalc.multiply.myCurry(Math.PI);
myCalc.multiplyPi(1);          // returns 3.141592653589793
myCalc.back();                 // returns "3.141592653589793 * 1"
```

However, I feel like if Douglas Crockford did it his way, he probably has a good reason. What am I missing?

Comment: I'd say that's partial application, not particularly currying. For a `curry` implementation that preserves the context, take a look at how [LiveScript](http://livescript.net) [does it](https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/3b54b887d519a4998a36), works great.

Comment: It's actually the 'history' array that is undefined. Your fix is a good one! Crockford's implementation doesn't take into account the use of 'classes'.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply explains null there

Comment: @epascarello, so `null` is replaced with the global object. I feel like that makes it worse, because you could have a situation where an error is not thrown even though `this` is not what is expected.

Comment: @elclanrs, its going to take me a while to digest that code, but it looks like an optional argument can be used to set context, otherwise `this` is used, which seems like a good idea to me. If I understand it correctly, which I am not sure that I do.

Comment: It works with `this` by default, yes. It's mostly seamless, and it implements currying the right way IMO, `add(1)(2)(3)`

Comment: @elclanrs, I think this is just semantics, with the wrong usage of the word "curry". I have updated my question to clarify that this is about partial application, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Not sure if there's a good reason behind Crockford's not using `this`. If you want explicitness you'd avoid `this` as much as possible, but I doubt that's the reason.

Comment: I would guess he did it to to force you to think about what the scope is during execution; to prevent you from assuming it's magic and that the scope stays the same by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reason 1 - not easy to provide a general solution

The problem is that your solution is not general. If the caller doesn't assign the new function to any object, or assigns it to a completely different object, your `multiplyPi` function will stop working:

```
var multiplyPi = myCalc.multiply.myCurry(Math.PI);
multiplyPi(1);  // TypeError: this.history.concat is not a function
```

So, neither Crockford's nor your solution can assure that the function will be used correctly. Then it may be easier to say that the `curry` function works only on "functions", not "methods", and set `this` to `null` to force that. We might only speculate though, since Crockford doesn't mention that in the book.

### Reason 2 - functions are being explained

If you asking "why Crockford didn't use this or that" - the very likely answer is: *"It wasn't important in regard to the demonstrated matter."* Crockford uses this example in the chapter **Functions**. The purpose of the sub-chapter `curry` was:

- to show that functions are objects you can create and manipulate
- to demonstrate another usage of closures
- to show how arguments can be manipulated.

Finetuning this for a general usage with objects was not purpose of this chapter. As it is problematic if not even impossible (see Reason 1), it was more educational to put there just `null` instead if putting there *something* which could raise questions if it actually works or not (didn't help in your case though :-)).

### Conclusion

That said, I think you can be perfectly confident in your solution! There's no particular reason in your case to follow Crockfords' decision to reset `this` to `null`. **You must be aware though that your solution only works under certain circumstances, and is not 100% clean. Then clean "object oriented" solution would be *to ask the object* to create a clone of its method inside itself,** to ensure that the resultant method will stay within the same object.

Answer (score 4):

> But what I want to know is why does he set this to null?

There is not really a reason. Probably he wanted to simplify, and most functions that make sense to be curried or partially applied are not OOP-methods that use `this`. In a more functional style the `history` array that is appended to would be another parameter of the function (and maybe even a return value).

> Wouldn't the expected behavior be that the curried method is the same as the original, including the same this?

Yes, your implementation makes much more sense, however one might not expect that a partially applied function still needs to be called in the correct context (as you do by re-assigning it to your object) if it uses one.

For those, you might have a look at the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) of Function objects for partial application including a specific `this`-value.

Answer (score 4):

**Reader beware, you're in for a scare.**

There's a lot to talk about when it comes to currying, functions, partial application and object-orientation in JavaScript. I'll try to keep this answer as short as possible but there's a lot to discuss. Hence I have structured my article into several sections and at the end of each I have summarized each section for those of you who are too impatient to read it all.

---

## 1. To curry or not to curry

Let's talk about Haskell. In Haskell every function is curried by default. For example we could create an `add` function in Haskell as follows:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add a b = a + b
```

Notice the type signature `Int -> Int -> Int`? It means that `add` takes an `Int` and returns a function of type `Int -> Int` which in turn takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`. This allows you to partially apply functions in Haskell easily:

```
add2 :: Int -> Int
add2 = add 2
```

The same function in JavaScript would look ugly:

```
function add(a) {
    return function (b) {
        return a + b;
    };
}

var add2 = add(2);
```

The problem here is that functions in JavaScript are not curried by default. You need to manually curry them and that's a pain. Hence we use partial application (aka [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) instead.

**Lesson 1:** Currying is used to make it easier to partially apply functions. However it's only effective in languages in which functions are curried by default (e.g. Haskell). If you have to manually curry functions then it's better to use partial application instead.

---

## 2. The structure of a function

Uncurried functions also exist in Haskell. They look like functions in "normal" programming languages:

```
main = print $ add(2, 3)

add :: (Int, Int) -> Int
add(a, b) = a + b
```

You can convert a function in its curried form to its uncurried form and vice versa using the [`uncurry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) and [`curry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:curry) functions in Haskell respectively. An uncurried function in Haskell still takes only one argument. However that argument is a product of multiple values (i.e. a [product type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type)).

In the same vein functions in JavaScript also take only a single argument (it just doesn't know it yet). That argument is a product type. The `arguments` value inside a function is a manifestation of that product type. This is exemplified by the `apply` method in JavaScript which takes a product type and applies a function to it. For example:

```
print(add.apply(null, [2, 3]));
```

Can you see the similarity between the above line in JavaScript and the following line in Haskell?

```
main = print $ add(2, 3)
```

Ignore the assignment to `main` if you don't know what it's for. It's irrelevant apropos to the topic at hand. The important thing is that the tuple `(2, 3)` in Haskell is isomorphic to the array `[2, 3]` in JavaScript. What do we learn from this?

The `apply` function in JavaScript is the same as function application (or `$`) in Haskell:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ a = f a
```

We take a function of type `a -> b` and apply it to a value of type `a` to get a value of type `b`. However since all functions in JavaScript are uncurried by default the `apply` function always takes a product type (i.e. an array) as its second argument. That is to say that the value of type `a` is actually a product type in JavaScript.

**Lesson 2:** All functions in JavaScript only take a single argument which is a product type (i.e. the `arguments` value). Whether this was intended or happenstance is a matter of speculation. However the important point is that you understand that mathematically every function only takes a single argument.

Mathematically a function is defined as a [morphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism): `a -> b`. It takes a value of type `a` and returns a value of type `b`. A morphism can only have one argument. If you want multiple arguments then you could either:

1. Return another morphism (i.e. `b` is another morphism). This is currying. Haskell does this.
2. Define `a` to be a product of multiple types (i.e. `a` is a product type). JavaScript does this.

Out of the two I prefer curried functions as they make partial application trivial. Partial application of "uncurried" functions is more complicated. Not difficult, mind you, but just more complicated. This is one of the reasons why I like Haskell more than JavaScript: functions are curried by default.

---

## 3. Why OOP matters not

Let's take a look at some object-oriented code in JavaScript. For example:

```
var oddities = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(odd).length;

function odd(n) {
    return n % 2 !== 0;
}
```

Now you might wonder how is this object-oriented. It looks more like functional code. After all you could do the same thing in Haskell:

```
oddities = length . filter odd $ [0..9]
```

Nevertheless the above code is object-oriented. The array literal is an object which has a method `filter` which returns a new array object. Then we simply access the `length` of the new array object.

What do we learn from this? Chaining operations in object-oriented languages is the same as composing functions in functional languages. The only difference is that the functional code reads backwards. Let's see why.

In JavaScript the `this` parameter is special. It's separate from the formal parameters of the function which is why you need to specify a value for it separately in the `apply` method. Because `this` comes before the formal parameters, methods are chained from left-to-right.

```
add.apply(null, [2, 3]); // this comes before the formal parameters
```

If `this` were to come after the formal parameters the above code would probably read as:

```
var oddities = length.filter(odd).[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

apply([2, 3], null).add; // this comes after the formal parameters
```

Not very nice is it? Then why do functions in Haskell read backwards? The answer is currying. You see functions in Haskell also have a "`this`" parameter. However unlike in JavaScript the `this` parameter in Haskell is not special. In addition it comes at the end of the argument list. For example:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The `filter` function takes a predicate function and a `this` list and returns a new list with only the filtered elements. So why is the `this` parameter last? It makes partial application easier. For example:

```
filterOdd = filter odd
oddities = length . filterOdd $ [0..9]
```

In JavaScript you would write:

```
Array.prototype.filterOdd = [].filter.myCurry(odd);
var oddities = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filterOdd().length;
```

Now which one would you choose? If you're still complaining about reading backwards then I have news for you. You can make Haskell code read forwards using "backward application"  and "backward composition" as follows:

```
($>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
a $> f = f a

(>>>) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
f >>> g = g . f

oddities = [0..9] $> filter odd >>> length
```

Now you have the best of both worlds. Your code reads forwards and you get all the benefits of currying.

There are a lot of problems with `this` that don't occur in functional languages:

1. The `this` parameter is specialized. Unlike other parameters you can't simply set it to an arbitrary object. Hence you need to use `call` to specify a different value for `this`.
2. If you want to partially apply functions in JavaScript then you need to specify `null` as the first parameter of `bind`. Similarly for `call` and `apply`.

Object-oriented programming has nothing to do with `this`. In fact you can write object-oriented code in Haskell as well. I would go as far as to say that Haskell is in fact an object-oriented programming language, and a far better one at that than Java or C++.

**Lesson 3:** Functional programming languages are more object-oriented than most mainstream object-oriented programming languages. In fact object-oriented code in JavaScript would be better (although admittedly less readable) if written in a functional style.

The problem with object-oriented code in JavaScript is the `this` parameter. In my humble opinion the `this` parameter shouldn't be treated any differently than formal parameters (Lua got this right). The problem with `this` is that:

1. There's no way to set `this` like other formal parameters. You have to use `call` instead.
2. You have to set `this` to `null` in `bind` if you wish to only partially apply a function.

On a side note I just realized that every section of this article is becoming longer than the preceding section. Hence I promise to keep the next (and final) section as short as possible.

---

## 4. In defense of Douglas Crockford

By now you must have picked up that I think that most of JavaScript is broken and that you should shift to Haskell instead. I like to believe that Douglas Crockford is a functional programmer too and that he is trying to fix JavaScript.

How do I know that he's a functional programmer? He's the guy that:

1. Popularized the functional equivalent of the `new` keyword (a.k.a `Object.create`). If you don't already do then you should [stop using the `new` keyword](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#stop_using_the_new_keyword).
2. Attempted to explain the concept of [monads and gonads](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkZFtimgAcM) to the JavaScript community.

Anyway, I think Crockford nullified `this` in the `curry` function because he knows how bad `this` is. It would be sacrilege to set it to anything other than `null` in a book entitled "JavaScript: The Good Parts". I think he's making the world a better place one feature at a time.

By nullifying `this` Crockford is forcing you to stop relying on it.

---

**Edit:** As Bergi requested I'll describe a more functional way to write your object-oriented `Calculator` code. We will use Crockford's `curry` method. Let's start with the `multiply` and `back` functions:

```
function multiply(a, b, history) {
    return [a * b, [a + " * " + b].concat(history)];
}

function back(history) {
    return [history[0], history.slice(1)];
}
```

As you can see the `multiply` and `back` functions don't belong to any object. Hence you can use them on any array. In particular your `Calculator` class is just a wrapper for list of strings. Hence you don't even need to create a different data type for it. Hence:

```
var myCalc = [];
```

Now you can use Crockford's `curry` method for partial application:

```
var multiplyPi = multiply.curry(Math.PI);
```

Next we'll create a `test` function to `multiplyPi` by one and to go back to the previous state:

```
var test = bindState(multiplyPi.curry(1), function (prod) {
    alert(prod);
    return back;
});
```

If you don't like the syntax then you could switch to [LiveScript](http://livescript.net/):

```
test = do
    prod <- bindState multiplyPi.curry 1
    alert prod
    back
```

The `bindState` function is the `bind` function of the state monad. It's defined as follows:

```
function bindState(g, f) {
    return function (s) {
        var a = g(s);
        return f(a[0])(a[1]);
    };
}
```

So let's put it to the test:

```
alert(test(myCalc)[0]);
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/5h5R9/

BTW this entire program would have been more succinct if written in LiveScript as follows:

```
multiply = (a, b, history) --> [a * b, [a + " * " + b] ++ history]

back = ([top, ...history]) -> [top, history]

myCalc = []

multiplyPi = multiply Math.PI

bindState = (g, f, s) -->
    [a, t] = g s
    (f a) t

test = do
    prod <- bindState multiplyPi 1
    alert prod
    back

alert (test myCalc .0)
```

See the demo of the compiled LiveScript code: http://jsfiddle.net/5h5R9/1/

So how is this code object oriented? Wikipedia defines [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) as:

> Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm that represents concepts as "objects" that have data fields (attributes that describe the object) and associated procedures known as methods. Objects, which are usually instances of classes, are used to interact with one another to design applications and computer programs.

According to this definition functional programming languages like Haskell are object-oriented because:

1. In Haskell we represent concepts as [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) which are essentially "objects on steroids". An ADT has one or more constructors which may have zero or more data fields.
2. ADTs in Haskell have associated functions. However unlike in mainstream object-oriented programming languages ADTs don't own the functions. Instead the functions specialize upon the ADTs. This is actually a good thing as ADTs are open to adding more methods. In traditional OOP languages like Java and C++ they are closed.
3. ADTs can be made instances of typeclasses which are similar to interfaces in Java. Hence you still do have inheritance, variance and subtype polymorphism but in a much less intrusive form. For example `Functor` is a superclass of `Applicative`.

The above code is also object-oriented. The object in this case is `myCalc` which is simply an array. It has two functions associated with it: `multiply` and `back`. However it doesn't own these functions. As you can see the "functional" object-oriented code has the following advantages:

1. Objects don't own methods. Hence it's easy to associate new functions to objects.
2. Partial application is made simple via currying.
3. It promotes generic programming.

So I hope that helped.

Comment: You don't need to curry JS functions manually (by nesting functions), you can do it programmatically (with a functional method)!

Comment: `[].filter.bind(null, odd)` does not work - you cannot call it on arbitrary arrays any more. You would need to use the OP's partial application `[].filter.myCurry(odd)`!

Comment: Although I really love Haskell and functional programming, I don't think that "*object-oriented code in JavaScript would be better if written in a functional style*". "Better" in terms of what? Also the statement "*Functional programming languages are more object-oriented than most mainstream object-oriented programming languages*" needs more explanation; while I believe I can guess what you're aiming at I'm not sure and think most readers will not understand it at all. Maybe you rather should transform this answer into one of your interesting blog posts!

Comment: "*By nullifying `this` Crockford is forcing you to stop relying on it.*" Good answer to the actual question! However, for an upvote from me you should also include a code example of how to build the OPs `Calculator` in an object-orientated, functional way without `this`.

Comment: @Bergi I edited my answer explaining how 1) "functional" OOP is better than traditional OOP 2) Haskell is more object-oriented than Java or C++ 3) the OP's `Calculator` code can be written in a "functional" OOP style.

Comment: You've written a novel and near as I can tell about 95% of it is off-topic. This is suitable for blog post, not really suitable for a Q&A website where the goal is connect people with answers *quickly*. If you can answer in more words or fewer, you should always choose fewer.

Comment: Thanks, +1! However, meagar is right and you should move sections 1-3 to your blog and link it :-)

Comment: I am impressed that you took the time to be so thorough, but it would've been better if you just used javascript, no Haskell. I can think of several ways to make the calculator without using `this`, I purposely used `this` so I could have a simple example expose the problem. My issue is that if you are adding a method to `Function`, it better work with whatever the next guy to work on the code throws at it. Competent programmers may use `this`, causing a silent failure because `this` exists, but is set to the global object.  I would summarize your answer as 'It is better not to use `this`'.

Comment: @AaditMShah, you are probably right about Crockford, BTW. The reason myself, Douglas Crockford, and a bajillion other people use javascript is mainly because we are working on websites, and we need code that will run in every browser without the user having to install something. So we must use javascript, I couldn't use Haskell if I wanted to.

Comment: @AaditMShah, just for you, and Douglas Crockford, I will rewrite the example without using the `new` keyword.  :)

Comment: @RustyToms I agree. There's no good reason to add methods to native prototypes. Especially if they don't work as one would expect them to. Yes we're stuck with JavaScript but it's actually not so bad. Considering the history of JavaScript and the web we should have been stuck with a language that is far worse. That being said I still love JavaScript. I've been working in JavaScript since 8 years. It's my primary language. However working with other languages like Haskell and Lua have showed me the shortcomings of JavaScript and I hope to see it being fixed in the next version of ECMAScript. =)

Comment: I know it's been a while but the comparison of composition (FP) and method chaining (OOP) or ADTs and "classical objects" is really remarkable! It is a pity that this answer is hiding behind a indeed interesting but also very specific question. I am glad to have tracked it down.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> thisArg The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this
>   may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a
>   function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced
>   with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

Hence, if the method is in non-strict mode and the first argument is `null` or `undefined`, `this` inside of that method will reference `Window`. In strict mode, this is `null` or `undefined`. I've added a live example on [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anzeo/S8Z92/).

Furthermore passing in `null`or `undefined` does not do any harm in case the function does not reference `this` at all. That's probably why Crockford used `null` in his example, to not overcomplicate things.