# Why is call necessary in this Javascript example?

Tags: javascript

Here's the problem (called "Compose functions (T Combinator)" on codewars.com, in case you want to try it out in the original environment):

Let's make a function called compose that accepts a value as a parameter, as well as any number of functions as additional parameters.

The function will return the value that results from the first parameter being used as a parameter for all of the accepted function parameters in turn. If only a single parameter is passed in, return that parameter.

So:

```
var doubleTheValue = function(val) { return val * 2; }
var addOneToTheValue = function(val) { return val + 1; }

compose(5, doubleTheValue) // should === 10
compose(5, doubleTheValue, addOneToTheValue) // should === 11
```

Here was one of the possible solutions:

```
var compose = function(initialValue) {
  var functions = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return functions.reduce(function(previousResult, func){
    return func.call(this, previousResult);
  }, initialValue); 
}
```

Why do we need to return func.call(this, previousResult) rather than just func(previousResult)? The latter only works in some cases. What will "this" default to without the call?

Comment: You are drilling into the hierarchy.

Comment: Hopefully at least one of our answers made sense, but I think this Q is answered fully with all the info provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we need to return `func.call(this, previousResult)` rather than just `func(previousResult)`?

We don't really. `this` is not the [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of the `compose` function (what the author probably intended), but of the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) callback - where it [is specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21) to be `undefined`.

> What will "this" default to without the call?

`undefined` as well, see [Why is "this" in an anonymous function undefined when using strict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822561/why-is-this-in-an-anonymous-function-undefined-when-using-strict).

Comment: Hi Bergi, you said that we don't really need to return func.call(this, previousResult), but if I change the code to just func(previousResult), then it does not pass the exercise. Any insight on why this might be?

Comment: Unfortunately that link requires a login, and I'm not familiar with codewars. But it might always be that an answer is incorrect :-) Ask the creator of the exercise! Also you might be interested in the question [Is there a reason why `this` is nullified in Crockford's `curry` method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21002417/1048572), where is explained how `this` should be irrelevant in functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

In strict mode, `this` will be `undefined` since there is no calling context.

In non-strict Javascript it will be the global object (`window` in a browser).

Comment: That partly clarifies things for me, but what does setting this as "this" do in the given solution? If I passed compose only functions that did arithmetic operations, then I wouldn't need to use call. I can think of a few examples of functions where I would have to use call, in the sense that having an undefined this would screw things up, but I don't see why the passing this to the call makes everything okay?

Comment: If you need to access other `functions` in the `window`, how would your call understand what is cached and whatnot looking for only `function name` **rather than** `window` -> `function name`?

Comment: Sure I follow that, but where in the code would I need to access other functions in the window? Each func is being passed by the reduce and they exist in that scope?

Answer (score 0):

**Why do we need to return func.call(this, previousResult) rather than just func(previousResult)?**

### `this` defaults to our `window`.

Basically, we're giving it a `secondary value` in order to further our progression down the line.

If you were to call simply `previousResult`, the `JS` doesn't know where to look to find such a thing. Your are referencing the `window` if you don't call a prior `parameter`. This is very common in most **OOP languages**. You can't look for your value *IN* `window` without further defining that you want something `IN window`.

Essentially, we are just providing a *bogus* variable in order to get to the next step in the chain. You will see this a lot with `Python` and `Ruby` code.

The reason you set `this` is because `this` will equal the `parent window`, then you know you can find the next `variable` within that particular `parameter`.

**Simple Example:**
It's sort of like trying to call a `variable` in a different `function`. Just doesn't work without defining your `scope` first.

Comment: Thanks :-) Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: You said "If you were to call simply previousResult, the JS doesn't know where to look to find such a thing". But previousResult is a parameter in the callback function for reduce, so wouldn't it be known?

Comment: You'd be surprised how `Javascript` handles data. It still has quite a few quirks. And yes, you **would** think, but unfortunately calling `any data` on it won't work in that situation. Let me dig up a reference for you :-)